# Create Javascript dates as UTC

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to format Dates in Javascript and format them into Month Year, e.g. "January 2020", but I can't seem to get around timezones. For example:

```js
const date = new Date('2020-01-01');

// I expect to be able to get the year (2020) from this date...
console.log(date.getFullYear()); // Output: 2019
console.log(date); // Output: Tue Dec 31 2019 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

You would think I could just use `getUTCFullYear`:

```js
console.log(date.getUTCFullYear()); // Outputs '2020' like I would excpect.
```

... But if I want to use `date-fns` to format the date:

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns';

console.log(format(date, 'MMMM yyyy')); // Outputs 'December 2019'
```

This is really frustrating. Coming from PHP which seems to be able to handle this flawlessly, I'm pretty lost. How can I just treat all dates as UTC and ignore the timezone?

Comment: Side note: Personally I prefer the [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) library, it is much more user friendly and robust in functionality.

Comment: It seems to be the fault of *date-fns* not to use UTC.

Answer (score 0):

use `utcToZonedTime` like

```
const { utcToZonedTime, format } = require('date-fns-timezone')
const timeZone = 'Europe/Berlin'
const date = new Date('2020-01-01');
const zonedDate = utcToZonedTime(date, timeZone)
const pattern = 'MMMM yyyy'
const output = format(zonedDate, pattern, { timeZone })
```

Answer (score 0):

When constructing a `Date` without a time, JavaScript assumes the timezone of the supplied date is UTC.

If you want to explicitly supply a date/time in terms of UTC, you must use `Date.UTC`:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)) // note: zero-based months
console.log(date.toISOString()) // 2020-01-01T01:00:00.000Z (Z means UTC)
```

Internally, `Date` stores the number of milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC), but unless a method explicitly specifies it will return a value in UTC, most `Date` methods return a value in terms of the locale configured on your local machine.

So, invoking the `getFullYear` method will return the year at that UTC time, **transformed for your locally configured locale**. In your case, 2020-01-01T00:00:00 UTC was some time in 2019 because your locale is "behind" UTC. This is why the method `getUTCFullYear` exists.

Something appears to have been lost in translation with the library you are using. Fortunately JavaScript has comprehensive Date/Time formatting [built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat).

You can pull out the relevant bits from the code below:

```js
const utcFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", { month: "long", year: "numeric", timeZone: "UTC", timeZoneName: 'short' })
const laFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "long", year: "numeric", timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles", timeZoneName: 'short' })

const date = new Date("2020-01-01") // 2020-01-01T00:00:00 UTC

const d1 = utcFormatter.formatToParts(date);
console.log(`${d1[0].value} ${d1[2].value} ${d1[4].value}`) // January 2020 UTC

const d2 = laFormatter.formatToParts(date)
console.log(`${d2[0].value} ${d2[2].value} ${d2[4].value}`) // December 2019 PST
```